# How to convert lists of lines in strings to lists of lists, with each item in the lines stripped

Tags: python

I want to convert lists of lines in strings to lists of lists, with each item in the lines stripped.

The following works, but I suspect there is a sleeker way to do this.

```
def str_to_lst_of_lsts(s):
    lst = s.splitlines()[1:]
    lst2 = [i.split(';') for i in lst]
    lst3 = []
    for i in lst2:
        i2 = [j.strip() for j in i]
        lst3.append(i2)
    return lst3

s = '''
c; German for dog; Hund
c; capital of France; Paris
c; company; IBM
c; nation; Sweden
c; nickname for James; Jim
'''

print(str_to_lst_of_lsts(s))

# [['c', 'German for dog', 'Hund'], ['c', 'capital of France', 'Paris'], ['c', 'company', 'IBM'], ['c', 'nation', 'Sweden'], ['c', 'nickname for James', 'Jim']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested string comprehension

```
def str_to_lst_of_lsts(s):
    return [
        [part.strip() for part in line.split(';')]
        for line in s.splitlines()[1:]
    ]
```

Comment: Even better -- perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The main step is to use a list comprehension in place of the loop:

```
lst3 = [[j.strip() for j in i] for i in lst2]
```

Yes, you can nest list comprehensions.  Now *if* you insist on a one-line solution, you can substitute the previous two comprehensions into this one.

Coding style: don't do it.  :-)

Comment: Nested list comprehensions -- got it. Elegant.

Comment: Elegant, but when you do it, make sure you keep it readable.  Good names for the temporary variables can help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work also -

```
p = s.split("\n")
l = [x.split(";")  for x in p if x != ""]
print l
>>> [['c', ' German for dog', ' Hund'], ['c', ' capital of France', ' Paris'], ['c', ' company', ' IBM'], ['c', ' nation', ' Sweden'], ['c', ' nickname for James', ' Jim']]
```